# How do I convert from RT90 to WGS84 in R?

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, wgs84

I have a dataset with a bunch of data in RT90 format. E.g 6275755 1538971 should be around 56.607512 16.439838 in WGS84, according to this [online converter.](https://www.trf.se/rt90/) How can I do this using R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for "RT90" on epsg.io shows a few codes that I guess match to the various options on that web page. So let's try:

```
> x = 6275755
> y = 1538971
```

Then with a bit of trial and error on the various codes, and flipping x and y in the coordinates...

```
> library(sf)
> st_transform(st_sfc(st_point(c(y,x)), crs=3021), 4326)
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 16.43984 ymin: 56.60751 xmax: 16.43984 ymax: 56.60751
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
POINT (16.43984 56.60751)
>
```

Which is bob on to what you've got from the web page. So I'd say your coordinates were in EPSG 3021 coordinates. Or near enough.